# Renderproblem RichTextBox Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, richtextbox, windows-phone-8

I'm implemented a RichTextBox in WindowsPhone 8. I fill this Box while runtime with Paragraphs, Runs, Images and HyperlinkButtons. The Problem that now appears is after some lines of content the RichTextBox is cut. I declared a red border that is also cut. Links and images are still displayed.
Here is a Screenshot:
[image: Error Screenshot]

My XamlCode is simple:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <RichTextBox x:Name="ContentBox"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red" >
        </RichTextBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Any idea what the problem is or is it a simulator bug?

Comment: Have you edited the RichTextBox's Control Template ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the link in your rich text? Does the other text display correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the fill-rate counter is at 2.4 my crystal ball tells me that you're hitting the 4096px limit of size for a single UI element. If that's the case you'll have to split up the RichTextBox content between several different controls.

Comment: Thanks, you respectivly your cristal balls ;) are right. One question left, do you've a source for the maximum control size?

Comment: I couldn't find it despite web searching again but i remember seeing it was an increase from the 2048x2048 max size in WP8.