# RichTextBox in Windows Phone 8 cuts long content

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have next XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Height="Auto">
    <RichTextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
       <Paragraph>
           Lorem ipsum ....
       </Paragraph>
    </RichTextBox>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If you set very long text to a paragraph, lets say 10000+ bytes long - displayed content is cut even though the control height is ok:

[image]

How to make it render content correctly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renderproblem RichTextBox Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875675/renderproblem-richtextbox-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13875675/renderproblem-richtextbox-windows-phone-8). Apparently, the max size height on a control is 4096 px.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Got it done by splitting text into bunch of RichTextBoxes wrapped into ItemsControl.